# Admob force permissions : Location and local content

Tags: android, permissions, location, admob

I have successfully integrated AdMob in my app, but it ask for new permissions when i generate the apk :

- Access location
- Read & write local content

I don't want ads to target my users.

Here is my permissions in manifest file :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

How can i disable unwanted permissions ?

**EDIT**

I've found !

It was the google play services integration in build.gradle. I used all the features but I only needed to advertise.

Before :

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
```

After :

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:7.5.0'
```

And it works !

Comment: admod does't require these permissions.The location permission may be optional for localisation of ads but they are not compulsory.See if any other feature in your app requires these permissions.